# How is the transfer function block in simulink labelled as linear ? especially for the cases where variable 's' has power greater than 1

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, linear, simulink, non-linear

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html

Above weblink gives description about the transfer function block in simulink. I am confused why it is written in the description at top of this web page **Model linear system by transfer function**

There are many cases where the transfer function especially  its denominator will involve non unity(greater than 1) power/exponent of variable of 's'. Forexample transfer function of a series RLC circuit where transfer function has s^2 in denominator and due to s^2 our system will not be linear because highest power is 2 in this scenario which is greater than 1(power for ideal scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A linear transfer function defines that the ratio of output/input is independent of the input level.**

- Using a step input, the output can have exponential signals which play an important role in linear systems. They appear in the solution of the differential equation.
- It's the ratio of this equation that is linear so even with exponential responses.
- The gain or attenuation has a linear response when the ratio is unchanged with input amplitude.
- Transfer Linearity is usually measured in terms of a deviation, or nonlinearity, from an ideal straight line and it is typically expressed in terms of percent of full scale, or in ppm (parts per million) of full scale and thus independent of the input amplitude.
- a nonlinear transfer function is dependent on the input level where the ratio changes at some point with the input level.

A linear function f(x) is a function that satisfies the two properties:[1]

1. Additivity: f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y).
2. Homogeneity of degree 1: f(αx) = α f(x) for all α.

Comment: Please try to reconsider your answer. Are you sure, if a system(transfer function) has s^2 or any other higher power in numerator or denominator, still that system will be cosnidered linear?and this simulink block is valid for use with such systems?

Comment: **yes I'm sure** the exponential series applies to the frequency response with varying powers of slope (poles and zeros) not the sensitivity to input level. Pls re-read the answer then have a better question.